# MarkLogic: Finding related articles

Tags: marklogic

I have a huge database of records. When I view some record, I need to find related records to this particular record and list them down. You might have seen this in many websites like they provide "suggested sites" or "suggested articles" or "you may be also interested in..." also etc.. Can you please help me how can we achieve this with MarkLogic? I am using ML6.0.2.

Comment: You’ll have to define what “related” means in the context of your application? Written by the same author? Containing the same key words? There are many levers in MarkLogic that you can use to achieve these and other notions of “related”, but you’ll need to be more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If your record document contains `hard-coded` links to other record documents (that is, embeds the document URIs of related record documents), you can search for those document URIs, extract elements from those record documents for the listing.

As an alternative to hard-coded links, you can construct an on-the-fly list of similar record documents with the `return-similar` option in `search:search()` or `cts:similar-query()` in `cts:search()`.

One other alternative is to embed a query within each record document that matches similar record documents.  Strip out the embedded query when displaying a record document and execute the embedded query to find related record documents.  For a more selectivity, you can use the match-making technique by and-ing the embedded query with a reverse query on the retrieved record document that matches the embedded queries in related record documents.